# AMCharts - How to specify the color scheme for each category in a stacked column chart?

Tags: amcharts4

My goal is to create a stacked column chart which shows two distinct categories of data, each with its own color scheme (category 1 in blue, category 2 in yellow):

[image]

Is this possible using AMCharts version 4?

I've simplified the [stacked column chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-column-chart/) demo to create this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/wxrb0zdm/6/):

[image]

How can I apply separate colors to the 2016 and 2017 columns? I tried adding a range of colors to `charts.colors.list`:

```
chart.colors.list = [
  am4core.color("#845EC2"),
  am4core.color("#D65DB1"),
  am4core.color("#FF6F91"),
  am4core.color("#FF9671"),
  am4core.color("#FFC75F"),
  am4core.color("#F9F871")
];
```

... but both categories use the first 3 colors in the list. How can I force the second category to use the next color in the list, and not start over with the first color in the list?

Comment: Colors are set at the series level. If you need to customize colors based on a specific value/category use a propertyField and specify the colors directly in your dataset, similar to the [second solution I posted in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59870739/6106614)

Comment: @xorspark thanks again for the quick responses, much appreciated